# How to get new Intent extra when activity is brought to front?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When using a pendingIntent to start an activity and the activity is already active in the background, I can't get the new intent's extras.
getIntent returns **the intent that started the activity** but in this case, Android will just bring it back to front and call onResume. 
I want to be able to get new Extras in order to update the activity.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you passing `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag?

Comment: Yes I'm passing this flag. But I don't think it's related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

EDIT: Works when setting the activity launchmode to singleTask

Comment: Doesn't get called. The docs say: 'This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). '
BTW Tried it even with the single_top flag but it didn't get called. Anyway I don't want this flag

Answer (score 0):

The Intent is not same in onCreate and onNewIntent.
If Activity launch mode is singleTask or singleInstance, you do treat intent in two case.
please reads carefully : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

onNewIntent를 통해 들어오는 인텐트와 onCreate에서 갖어오는 인텐트(getIntent)는 다르다.